# RateLimit is doing weird maths and wrong numbers on kernel

Tags: networking, iptables, tcp, kernel, rate-limiting

I'm trying to apply a set of rate limit within iptables, and it's doing some weird maths that i'm not able to see on the kernel why this is happen.

I tried to execute same code on my local machine, and not on an aws instance and the result was the same, it's just increasing the numbers with a random ammount, the bigger the number the bigger the ammount is.

Following you will see the lines I executed and the rate limit that was finally applied.

Do you have any idea if that behaviour is currently a bug or if it's "an extrange feature"?

```
root@myserver:/opt/Project# iptables -w -t raw -L RATELIMIT
Chain RATELIMIT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

root@myserver:/opt/Project# iptables -w -t raw -A RATELIMIT -p tcp --dport 10430 -m limit --limit 7500 --limit-burst 4500 -j RETURN -m comment --comment "10430_allowed"
root@myserver:/opt/Project# iptables -w -t raw -L RATELIMIT
Chain RATELIMIT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:10430 limit: avg 10000/sec burst 4500 /* 10430_allowed */


root@myserver:/opt/Project# bash reset_ratelimit.sh
iptables: Chain already exists.
root@myserver:/opt/Project# iptables -w -t raw -A RATELIMIT -p tcp --dport 10430 -m limit --limit 7500 --limit-burst 5500 -j RETURN -m comment --comment "10430_allowed"
root@myserver:/opt/Project# iptables -w -t raw -L RATELIMIT
Chain RATELIMIT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:10430 limit: avg 10000/sec burst 5500 /* 10430_allowed */


root@myserver:/opt/Project# bash reset_ratelimit.sh
root@myserver:/opt/Project# iptables -w -t raw -A RATELIMIT -p tcp --dport 10430 -m limit --limit 1100 --limit-burst 1600 -j RETURN -m comment --comment "10430_allowed"
root@myserver:/opt/Project# iptables -w -t raw -L RATELIMIT
Chain RATELIMIT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:10430 limit: avg 1111/sec burst 1600 / 10430_allowed /
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:10430 / 10430_denied /
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my self.

This rule is supposed to limit the incoming TCP traffic on port 10430 to a rate of 1100 packets per second with a burst of 1600 packets. However, it's seems like as per kernel specifications this is really an average and not an specific and exact amount.

Apparently if I need something more exact i should use the command *tc* (traffic control) instead.

Comment: remind to accept your own answer after 24h, thanks